# Displaying data in gridview using jQuery ajax call is very slow

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview with id `gvRemarksHistory` and a button with id `btnLoadRemarks`.

I am using below code to bind data to gridview when clicked on button using jQuery ajax call

Code behind and jQuery code is as shown in image

[image]
[image]
[image]

My requirement is to display remarks in gridview. Above code working fine and fast when remarks data is too less.

I am having problem when the data is large. Suppose there are 10000 records, and I have implemented paging logic also. While page load I am displaying first 500 remarks and on next click I am displaying another 500 remarks ans so on... But each and every next/prev click data fetching is very very slow and in each click my page gets hanged till the process is completed.

Please suggest me the best way(s) to fetch and display the data in the grid.

Comment: You should edit your question and copy the text of your code into formatted code blocks in the question, then delete the images, they're impossible to read.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: So hard to help when this is what the question looks like to me http://i.imgur.com/2XB9IYe.png